asyncio.create_task executed even without any awaits in the program
This is a followup question to What does asyncio.create_task() do?
There, as well in other places, asyncio.create_task(c) is described as "immediately" running the coroutine c, when compared to simply calling the coroutine, which is then only executed when it is awaited.
It makes sense if you interpret "immediately" as "without having to await it", but in fact a created task is not executed until we run some await (possibly for other coroutines) (in the original question, slow_coro started being executed only when we await fast_coro).
However, if we do not run any await at all, the tasks are still executed (only one step, not to completion) at the end of the program:
import asyncio

async def counter_loop(x, n):
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        print(f"Counter {x}: {i}")
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
    return f"Finished {x} in {n}"


async def main():
    slow_task = asyncio.create_task(counter_loop("Slow", 4))
    fast_coro = asyncio.create_task(counter_loop("Fast", 2))
    print("Created tasks")
    for _ in range(1000):
        pass
    print("main ended")

asyncio.run(main())
print("program ended")

the output is
Created tasks
main ended
Counter Slow: 1
Counter Fast: 1
program ended

I am curious: why are the two created tasks executed at all if there was no await being run anywhere?

fwiw I actually said "submits the task to the event loop and returns immediately" rather than runs immediately, which I maintain is correct. Interesting discovery I was quite unaware of, though!

Does this answer your question? What Actually Triggers the Asyncio Tasks?

@2e0byo, thanks. I was actually referring to the short comment by Pynchia on the question itself, not your answer. What you wrote is correct.

@jupiterbjy, thanks, that is a very instructive answer but I don't think it addresses one of the issues here, namely that the tasks are still executed for one step before the program ends.

@jupiterbjy: oops, sorry, on further reflection I think it does answer it, although I guess I am still hoping to understand why the tasks are canceled merely because main has already exited. To me it would seem intuitive that the event loop would finish running all pending scheduled tasks, instead of canceling them. After all, they were created and scheduled, so it stands to reason the user wants them fully executed.

@user118967 updated answer to cover in detail including asyncio's source code, hope it helps! Honestly not sure if I should move that section to here or just keep it there making wall of text

Let's try to put it in these words:
the event loop enters execution with one task to be performed: the main().
When "main()" is complete, there are other two tasks ready to be processed - so before returning to main() caller, those are executed up the next await statement inside each one. (either an await or an async for or async with).
For the next loop iteration, as the main task is "over", the loop cancels the remaining tasks, and shuts down. This happens because what signals the loop that the "main" task is over is a callback that is set when loop.run_until_complete (called by asyncio.run) is done: it is this callback that signals that the loop should stop. But the callback itself will be executed only on the next loop iteration, after the main co-routine is done. And the loop iteration, even though gets a mark that the asyncio loop should stop there, will only actually shutdown after running once over all pending tasks - this implies in advancing each created task to the next await point.
This is done by throwing asyncio.CancelledError into the tasks code, at the await statement. So if you have a try/except/finally clause encompassing the await, you can still clean-up your task before the loop ends.
All of that is not documented in "English" - it is rather the current code behavior in the asyncio implementation. One have to follow the code at the
asyncio/base_events.py file to understand it.

Thank you! Followup question: would it be a more intuitive and natural design if the callback you are talking about ran immediately after main finishes? This could be achieved if run, as soon as called, wrapped the coroutine c it gets (here, main()) into a larger routine C that calls c and the callback:
def C():
    c()
    callback()

Then the callback is executed as soon as main() is over and the remaining tasks are cancelled right away, without having a chance to run even once.

Using create_task does add it too the eventloop. Even after leaving main, they are still there and active.
You need to actively cancel them before leaving main or set an await barrier at the start of the async function.
The loop is not aware that the code will soon end and will progress just as planned:
Note cancelled tasks will still run once sequentially up to the first await barrier (see: base_events.py executed from asycio.run_forevever)
Awaiting a task allows for the await... code to execute further (when possible)
